# How to: Generate cryptographically secure Random data of size quarter MB for a crypto application

Tags: random, cryptography, prng

I need to generate cryptographically secure random data file of size quarter MB. Any ideas how I can do this. Any libraries/ API's available. Please guide as I am a newbie in Cryto.

This data (gen) has to be an inut to a C program which has the following usage comments on the header:

crypto_prg g gfile sfile pfile mfile < gen: generates a code determined by
gen. writes code to gfile (7k), sfile (53k), pfile (4k), mfile (82k).
takes some time. encoding needs mfile. decoding needs gfile sfile pfile.
gen should be roughly a quarter megabyte of random data. gen without
enough random data may fail to generate a code. crypto_prg will warn you in
that case.

I need to generate the 'gen' in this case. How can I do that. Please advise as I am a newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: Does programming language matter?

Comment: no... I just need to input the data to a C program..I need the data file with random data..hw can i ddo this

Comment: C program would do..or any other u know of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can use a [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) to generate cryptographically secure data. If you only need to generate the data one time, then it would be simple enough to use the following:

RandomDataGenerator.java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[262144]; // Number of bytes in 0.25MB
    random.nextBytes(bytes);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("random.data");
        fos.write(myByteArray);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems getting this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on a *NIX based system (Linux, OSX, Android) you can simply read as many bytes as you need from the special file /dev/urandom.

See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key

Answer (score 0):

From a *NIX, you should rather use `/dev/random` than `/dev/urandom`, for random is slower but more secure.

Still on linux `APG` should be installed by default.
Try something like :

```
apg -a 1 -n 12 -m 16 -x 20 -M sncl
```

Finally you can use `PWGen` (not installed by default):

```
Cdt
```